# Can I search for and replace sections of a field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, search, replace

Here in an example field in a document:

```
  "html": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict\/\/EN\" \"http:\/\/www.test.org\/TR\/xhtml1\/DTD\/test.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.test.org\/1999\/xhtm [...]",
```

Buried within the field `html` are two ID numbers I need to use.  I need to search for one id and replace it.

Can i modify the following command?

```
db.user.update({html:"54506251bf2e4e753d8b5b69"},{$set:{html:"542de00c763f4a7f558be174"}},{multi:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not. Just out of luck because the database has not provided such functionality yet.
You may accomplish it by this way:

```
var oldId = "54506251bf2e4e753d8b5b69";
var newId = "542de00c763f4a7f558be174";
db.user.find({
    html : {
        $regex : oldId
    }
}, {
    html : 1
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    // fetch the field and modify it using JavaScript, then replace the one in database
    var newHtml = doc.html.replace(oldId, newId);
    db.user.update({
        _id : doc._id,
        html : {
            $regex : oldId
        }
    }, {
        $set : {
            html : newHtml
        }
    }, {
        multi : true
    });
});
```